# Exclude div children to have a global css rule and force them to inherite from parent

Tags: css, html, children

I have this CSS rule: 
`* {
    font:normal 12px puertoHelve,tahoma;
}`

Then I have divs like these (the children divs are created automatically):

```
<div class="asUserStyle" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:right;font-family:times new roman;font-size:16px;color:#000000;">
    test0
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
</div>
```

Now only test0 has the style applied to it but not the other divs; they have the previous rule.

Any ideas in CSS? If not, jQuery maybe..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/R7umu/2/

```
.asUserStyle div {
    //your other styles
}
```

**Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/R7umu/3/

So the div has to inherit all defined styles from `.asUserStyle`:

```
.asUserStyle div {
    margin: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    .....
}
```

Comment: The rules are not static, they are dynamic , each user can define them.